For reach row in dataframe, how to extract elements from an array?
I'm working with a third party dataset that includes location data. I'm trying to extract the Longitude and Latitude coordinates from the location column.  As stated in their doc:

The location column is of the point datatype.

When I ingest the data and view the location column it appears as below
>>> results_df["location"].iloc[1]
{'coordinates': array([-97.707172829666,  30.385328900508]), 'type': 'Point'}

Not all rows have a value, some are None.
I know I can do this to get the values for a specific row:
>>> results_df["location"].iloc[1]['coordinates'][0]
-97.707172829666
>>> results_df["location"].iloc[1]['coordinates'][1]
30.385328900508

But I'd like to create two new columns, longitude and latitude, for the entire dataframe.  For each row, how can I extract the coordinates to populate the new column?
Example:



latitude
longitude




30.385328900508
-97.707172829666


39.395338984595
-74.587966507573


None
None


42.396358150943
-104.664962196304


None
None



EDIT: I am working through the Pyspark Pandas API.

you can use lambda and apply for this:
import pandas as pd

def extract_coordinates(df):
    get_longitude = lambda x: x['coordinates'][0] if isinstance(x, dict) and 'coordinates' in x else None
    get_latitude = lambda x: x['coordinates'][1] if isinstance(x, dict) and 'coordinates' in x else None

    df['longitude'] = df['location'].apply(get_longitude)
    df['latitude'] = df['location'].apply(get_latitude)

    return df

sample_data = {
    'location': [
        {'coordinates': [-97.7071728296666, 30.385328900508], 'type': 'Point'},
        {'coordinates': [-74.587966507573, 39.395338984595], 'type': 'Point'},
        None,
        {'coordinates': [-104.66496219630, 42.396358150943], 'type': 'Point'},
        None
    ]
}

results_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
print("\nSample row from the dataset:")
print(results_df['location'].iloc[0])

results_df = extract_coordinates(results_df)
print("\nDataFrame with extracted coordinates:")
print(results_df)

results
$ python extract-ele-from-data.py

Sample row from the dataset:
{'coordinates': [-97.7071728296666, 30.385328900508], 'type': 'Point'}

DataFrame with extracted coordinates:
                                            location   longitude   latitude
0  {'coordinates': [-97.7071728296666, 30.3853289...  -97.707173  30.385329
1  {'coordinates': [-74.587966507573, 39.39533898...  -74.587967  39.395339
2                                               None         NaN        NaN
3  {'coordinates': [-104.6649621963, 42.396358150... -104.664962  42.396358
4                                               None         NaN        NaN


I forgot to add that i'm trying to work with the pyspark pandas api.  When I run your answer on pandas it works as expected.  But when I try to run through the pyspark pandas api I get the error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements

@MyNameHere can you edit your question and add a minimal reproducible example

I believe I did.  Please see my edit regarding pyspark pandas api and how your example does work with pandas, but does not work on pyspark pandas.

It should be similar to the above, however I used pyspark.pandas as you mentioned you are using pyspark pandas.
EDIT
import pyspark.pandas as ps
ps.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)

# Sample data (this matches your original structure)
sample_data = {
    'location': [
        {'coordinates': [-97.7071728296666, 30.385328900508], 'type': 'Point'},
        None,
        {'coordinates': [-74.587966507573, 39.395338984595], 'type': 'Point'},
        None,
        {'coordinates': [-104.66496219630, 42.396358150943], 'type': 'Point'},
    ]
}

# Create a PySpark Pandas DataFrame
results_df = ps.DataFrame(sample_data)

# Now add these Series to the DataFrame
results_df[['longitude','latitude']]= results_df.apply(lambda row: [row.location['coordinates'][0],row.location['coordinates'][1]] if row.location is not None else [None,None],axis=1, result_type="expand")


# Show the updated DataFrame
print(results_df)



I get the same error.  UserWarning: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true, but has reached the error below and can not continue. Note that 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' does not have an effect on failures in the middle of computation. ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements

Thanks for the feedback, I was able to reproduce your error, fixed and edited and attached screenshot. Let me know how you find it
